# Convert dict like string in separate columns in Python

Tags: python, string

we have a table with dict like string column as below.

| column_A |
| --- |
| {827056812014862 : [0.05, 0.0608, 0.476464, 0.53535]} |
| {263746262748835 : [0.08, 0.0333, 0.8263, 0.9463]} |
| {63673738736362 : [0.05, 0.0926, 0.8694, 0.9903]} |
| {73737681201484 : [0.08, 0.0425, 0.1948, 0.3958]} |

I am trying to create a separate column for every element in python.
Expected outcome:

| id | t1 | t2 | t3 | t4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 827056812014862 | 0.05 | 0.0608 | 0.476464 | 0.53535 |
| 263746262748835 | 0.08 | 0.0333 | 0.8263 | 0.9463 |
| 63673738736362 | 0.05 | 0.0926 | 0.8694 | 0.9903 |
| 73737681201484 | 0.08 | 0.0425 | 0.1948 | 0.3958 |

I tried converting the data frame in series and then concatenating it, but doesn't look like working it in above format.

Comment: Is the format of your table exactly like what is in first table?

Comment: Parse it as json? With the json package?

Comment: Yes @Mohsen_Fatemi

Comment: Yes @MatBailie I tried using ```json_normalize``` for parsing but it gives exact same string, not like columns.

Comment: @MatBailie This clearly isn't JSON, those are integer keys. The best solution would be to prevent the data from being serialized like this in the first place.

Comment: You need to define the format of your table; is it a Pandas DF or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values are strings, you can apply [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) on them and then construct new dataframe:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

out = []
for d in df["column A"].apply(literal_eval):
    for k, v in d.items():
        out.append({"id": k, **{f"t{i}": v for i, v in enumerate(v, 1)}})

out = pd.DataFrame(out)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
                id    t1      t2        t3       t4
0  827056812014862  0.05  0.0608  0.476464  0.53535
1  263746262748835  0.08  0.0333  0.826300  0.94630
2   63673738736362  0.05  0.0926  0.869400  0.99030
3   73737681201484  0.08  0.0425  0.194800  0.39580
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table = [
    {"column_A": {827056812014862: [0.05, 0.0608, 0.476464, 0.53535]}},
    {"column_A": {263746262748835: [0.08, 0.0333, 0.8263, 0.9463]}},
    {"column_A": {63673738736362: [0.05, 0.0926, 0.8694, 0.9903]}},
    {"column_A": {73737681201484: [0.08, 0.0425, 0.1948, 0.3958]}},
]

df_dict = {}
for item in table:
    for key,value in item["column_A"].items():
        df_dict[key] = value
        
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict, orient="index", columns=["t1","t2","t3","t4"]).reset_index()
df.columns = ["id","t1","t2","t3","t4"]

print(df)
```

Output:

[image]

For my second interpretation of your "table"

```
column_A = {
    827056812014862: [0.05, 0.0608, 0.476464, 0.53535],
    263746262748835: [0.08, 0.0333, 0.8263, 0.9463],
    63673738736362: [0.05, 0.0926, 0.8694, 0.9903],
    73737681201484: [0.08, 0.0425, 0.1948, 0.3958]
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(column_A, orient="index", columns=["t1","t2","t3","t4"]).reset_index()
df.columns = ["id","t1","t2","t3","t4"]
```

gives the same result.